# Ошибка при добавлении записи в SQLite

Tags: android, java, sqlite, sql

Добрый день! Не могу добавить запись в базу данных. Правильно ли я ею пользуюсь? Сперва общими переменной для класса своего парсера JSON строки объявил своего наследника SQLHelper и базу данных

```
public class JSONParser2Digma {
Context context;
SQLiteDataParadigma sqh; //хэлпер
SQLiteDatabase sqdb; //база данных
```

Далее в конструкторе парсера инициализирую хэлпер и базу данных

```
JSONParser2Digma(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    sqh = new SQLiteDataParadigma(context);
    sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Далее в теле парсера формирую строки и добавляю их в базу данных

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(SQLiteDataParadigma.UID, jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
cv.put(SQLiteDataParadigma.KEY_ADS_TITLE, jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
cv.put(SQLiteDataParadigma.KEY_ADS_BADGE, jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("badge"));
...
sqdb.insert(SQLiteDataParadigma.TABLE_NAME_ADS, SQLiteDataParadigma.UID, cv);
```

Однако всё заключается грустно, и в логи падает ошибка:

> 09-23 03:54:20.020   
> 787-787/com.saintvstudio.paradigma
> E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting
> vip=1 icon=ad_icon_4 category=4
> title=NL International _id=4
> updated=1409595381 created=1397490716
> status=1 vip_ad_order=100 ad_order=100
> badge=null
> url=http://2digma.ru/api/reklama/ad/4
>     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:
> error code 19: constraint failed
>             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native
> Method)

Что я делаю неправильно? Пользуюсь эмулятором из Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteConstraintException` однозначно свидетельствует о том, что добавляемая запись нарушает схему БД (`not null`, `unique` и т.д.). Покажите стектрейс исключения, и тогда станет возможным дать более точный ответ.

Пока же я могу предположить, что поле `badge` в таблице БД объявлено как `not null`. Проверьте схему данных и ограничения.

Comment: Удалил приложение, скомпилил заново. Ошибка не выходила. Скомпилил еще раз, ошибка вышла. Похоже, всё-таки работает достаточно правильно, просто уже находит такую запись и поверх записывать отказывается. Но тогда у меня встает другой вопрос (о считывании из базы), т.к. не удается считать, хотя выглядит так, будто в базе что-то есть. Но, видимо, лучше оформить отдельным вопросом.